# what is meant by " exact file attributes that are copied is platform and file system dependent " in Files.Copy() method?

Tags: java, file, path, copy, filesystems

I am going through java doc for Files class and copyOption enumeration. I did trail error by writing small java code on windows and understood the copy method usage in partial. What I don't understand is  the copyOption attribute "COPY_ATTRIBUTES" : it says 
"The exact file attributes that are copied is platform and file system dependent and therefore unspecified."  
 
 what is it mean?
 
Just for your reference see below. Taken from oracle java ;
`copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`
 
I have used copyOption "COPY_ATTRIBUTES" 
 COPY_ATTRIBUTES:  Attempts to copy the file attributes associated with this file to the target file. The exact file attributes that are copied is platform and file system dependent and therefore unspecified. Minimally, the last-modified-time is copied to the target file if supported by both the source and target file store. Copying of file timestamps may result in precision loss.

Comment: Windows has a set X of file attributes. Linux has a set Y.

Comment: Thank you. I did some reaing on wiki page after I see your reply.And I unerstood the attributes that are set based on Platform such as Windows , Linux and etc. Windows has it's own set of Attributes and so linux.